# Building Setup file with third- party DLL

Tags: c++, opencv, dll, visual-studio-2015, batch-build

I'm setting up a setup file for my app through **"Batch Build"** tool of **Visual Studio** to run on other machine, but the problem is that in my code contains 2 `DLL: "OpenCV"` and `"Chilkat"`. They make the compiler confused because compiler can't find their directory even though it works completely fine while I use **"Build Solution"**.

I have tried 2 method:

1. Add the dll to the dll of Visual Studio

`"D:\Visual Studio 2015\VC\include\"`, but the result is quite awful. I can't understand the errors what it says. Here is one of those errors.

```
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl cv::warpAffine(class cv::_InputArray const &,class cv::_OutputArray const &,class cv::_InputArray const &,class cv::Size_<int>,int,int,class cv::Scalar_<double> const &)" (?warpAffine@cv@@YAXAEBV_InputArray@1@AEBV_OutputArray@1@0V?$Size_@H@1@HHAEBV?$Scalar_@N@1@@Z) referenced in function "class cv::Mat __cdecl rotate(class cv::Mat &,double,struct CvPoint)" (?rotate@@YA?AVMat@cv@@AEAV12@NUCvPoint@@@Z)
```

2. Use the static directory to all the third party dll. Like this:

```
    #include <D:/OpenCV3.0/opencv/build/include/opencv2/opencv.hpp>
```

But it still fails because the header file only uses dynamic directory. It means if I use this way I have to change the directory of all header file.

**The question is:** How can I make the compiler recognize my third party dll when I use "Batch Build"? 
If anyone know something about this, please let me know. Thanks a lot.
Here is the code and the error

```
#include "cpprest/containerstream.h"
#include "cpprest/filestream.h"
#include "cpprest/http_client.h"
#include "cpprest/json.h"
#include "cpprest/producerconsumerstream.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <cstring>
#include <string>
#include <D:/Chilkat/chilkat-9.5.0-x86-vc2015/include/CkBinData.h>
#include <D:/OpenCV3.0/opencv/build/include/opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <D:/Chilkat/chilkat-9.5.0-x86-vc2015/include/CkXml.h>
#include <D:/Chilkat/chilkat-9.5.0-x86-vc2015/include/CkJsonObject.h>
#include <D:/OpenCV3.0/opencv/build/include/opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <D:/OpenCV3.0/opencv/build/include/opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <D:/OpenCV3.0/opencv/build/include/opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <D:/OpenCV3.0/opencv/build/include/opencv2/objdetect/objdetect.hpp>
#include <D:/Chilkat/chilkat-9.5.0-x86-vc2015/include/CkMime.h>
#include <D:/Chilkat/chilkat-9.5.0-x86-vc2015/include/CkByteData.h>
#include <D:/Chilkat/chilkat-9.5.0-x86-vc2015/include/CkFileAccess.h>
#include "conio.h"
#include <fstream>
#include <D:/OpenCV3.0/opencv/build/include/opencv2/face.hpp>
#include <direct.h>
#include <D:/OpenCV3.0/opencv/build/include/opencv2/face/facerec.hpp>
#include <D:/OpenCV3.0/opencv/build/include/opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
```

Error   C1083   Cannot open include file: 'opencv2/core.hpp': No such file or directory MicrosoftFaceAPI

Comment: 1. Do you can use CMake? It will more-more simplest.
2. In includes for absolutely paths use "" instead <>

Comment: I'm so sorry for late respond and thank you for your request. Here is my answer:
1. I have used CMake for my OpenCV so basically, I can use CMake but not outstanding.
2. I have replace the "" instead <> as you said but the result is the same. I think the compiler does not recognize any dll but the dll inside the Visual Studio.